# Merge all excel sheets into a one new Sheet

Tags: javascript, office-scripts, ms-office-script

I need your help, I have an Excel file type .xlsx, which was sent automatically from a system to my email, this Excel comes with the information distributed in several tabs within the same file, what I want to do is an Office script that takes the information from each of the sheets and unifies it into a single sheet, once all the data has been copied, delete all the sheets and the file is left with a single tab, with all the data unified. Thanks for your help.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get all the worksheets in the workbook
  let sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();

  // Create a new worksheet named "Consolidate"
  let consolidateSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Consolidate") || workbook.addWorksheet("Consolidate");

  // Loop through each sheet in the workbook
  for (let sheet of sheets) {
    // Get the data range of the current sheet
    let dataRange = sheet.getUsedRange();

    // Get the values from the data range
    let values = dataRange.getValues();

    // Find the last row with data in the Consolidate sheet
    let lastRow = consolidateSheet.getUsedRange().getRowCount();

    // Get the range where the data will be pasted in the Consolidate sheet
    let targetRange = consolidateSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length);

    // Paste the values into the Consolidate sheet
    targetRange.setValues(values);
  }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this a Java-related question but I don't see obvious relevance, and so you may wish to explain what this has to do with Java programming. Also, you have posted code, but may wish to explain it further, how it does what you want, what it doesn't do, the details of your code and your problem. Also, are you looking for someone to write code for you?

Comment: Is there a header row on each sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If the sheet named "Consolidate" is exist, you may need clear the sheet before collect data.
- `let values = dataRange.getValues()` includes the header row, then there are multiple header on Consolidate sheet.
- `getRangeByIndexes()` and `getRange()` are different.
- ***Note:*** Assuming there is a header row on each sheet.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get all the worksheets in the workbook
  let sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  const sumShtName = "Consolidate";
  // Create a new worksheet named "Consolidate"
  let consolidateSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sumShtName) || workbook.addWorksheet(sumShtName);
  // Clear sheet
  consolidateSheet.getRange().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
  // Loop through each sheet in the workbook
  for (let sheet of sheets) {
    // Get the data range of the current sheet
    if (sheet.getName() != sumShtName) {
      let dataRange = sheet.getUsedRange();
      let colCount = dataRange.getColumnCount();
      let rowCount = dataRange.getRowCount();
      // Copy table header
      if (!consolidateSheet.getRange("A1").getText()) {
        consolidateSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(dataRange.getAbsoluteResizedRange(1, colCount))
      }
      // Get the values from the data range, skip headser
      let values = dataRange.getOffsetRange(1, 0).getResizedRange(-1, 0).getValues();
      // Find the last row with data in the Consolidate sheet
      let lastRow = consolidateSheet.getUsedRange().getRowCount();
      // Get the range where the data will be pasted in the Consolidate sheet
      let targetRange = consolidateSheet.getRangeByIndexes(lastRow, 0, values.length, colCount);
      // Paste the values into the Consolidate sheet
      targetRange.setValues(values);
      sheet.delete();
    }
  }
}
```

---

Update:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get all the worksheets in the workbook
  let sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  const sumShtName = "Consolidate";
  const headerRows = 2;
  // Create a new worksheet named "Consolidate"
  let consolidateSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sumShtName) || workbook.addWorksheet(sumShtName);
  // Clear sheet
  consolidateSheet.getRange().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
  // Loop through each sheet in the workbook
  for (let sheet of sheets) {
    // Get the data range of the current sheet
    if (sheet.getName() != sumShtName) {
      let dataRange = sheet.getUsedRange();
      let colCount = dataRange.getColumnCount();
      let rowCount = dataRange.getRowCount();
      // Copy table header
      if (!consolidateSheet.getRange("A1").getText()) {
        consolidateSheet.getRange("A1").copyFrom(dataRange.getOffsetRange(headerRows-1,0).getAbsoluteResizedRange(1, colCount))
      }
      // Get the values from the data range, skip headser
      let values = dataRange.getOffsetRange(headerRows, 0).getResizedRange(-1 * headerRows, 0).getValues();
      // Find the last row with data in the Consolidate sheet
      let lastRow = consolidateSheet.getUsedRange().getRowCount();
      // Get the range where the data will be pasted in the Consolidate sheet
      let targetRange = consolidateSheet.getRangeByIndexes(lastRow, 0, values.length, colCount);
      // Paste the values into the Consolidate sheet
      targetRange.setValues(values);
      sheet.delete();
    }
  }
}
```

---

- Using `concat` method to consolidate the data and writing data to sheet all at once are more efficient.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  // Get all the worksheets in the workbook
  let sheets = workbook.getWorksheets();
  const sumShtName = "Consolidate";
  const headerRows = 2;
  // Create a new worksheet named "Consolidate"
  let consolidateSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sumShtName) || workbook.addWorksheet(sumShtName);
  // Clear sheet
  consolidateSheet.getRange().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
  let allValues: (string | number | boolean)[][] = [];
  let bFristSht: boolean = true;
  // Loop through each sheet in the workbook
  for (let sheet of sheets) {
    // Get the data range of the current sheet
    if (sheet.getName() != sumShtName) {
      let dataRange = sheet.getUsedRange();
      let values: (string | number | boolean)[][] = [];
      if (bFristSht) {
        // Get table with header from the 1st sheet
        values = dataRange.getOffsetRange(headerRows - 1, 0).getResizedRange(1 - headerRows, 0).getValues();
        bFristSht = !bFristSht;
      } else {
        // Get table w/o header
        values = dataRange.getOffsetRange(headerRows, 0).getResizedRange(-headerRows, 0).getValues();
      }
      allValues = allValues.concat(values);
      // sheet.delete
    }
  }
  // Get the range where the data will be pasted in the Consolidate sheet
  let targetRange = consolidateSheet.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, allValues.length, allValues[0].length);
  // Paste the values into the Consolidate sheet
  targetRange.setValues(allValues);
  console.log(allValues);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The code worked perfectly! Now all the data is copied to the new "Consolidate" sheet, could you apply this to me: "let values = dataRange.getValues() includes the header row, then there are multiple header on Consolidate sheet.", is that all the sheets They have 2 headings, in row A1, the title of the query appears and in row A2 the heading of each column appears. Is it possible with this parameter to copy from the second sheet, only the data after A2? Again, thank you very much.

Comment: `They have 2 headings` Does it mean the header occupies two rows?

Comment: Each sheet in the first row has the name of the query, over the entire table, this field is with a merge over all the data and in the second row, there are the headers of each column. Yes I know it's a little strange, but this is how the system sends the data.

Comment: Do you want to keep the query name on the merged sheet?

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much for your help, you don't know how long I've been trying to do it! Thank you so much !